# How to display total user count by specific role in WordPress as statistics?

Tags: shortcode, users, user-roles, count

i want to display in my Home page total user count by specific role in WordPress as statistics

I already created Role (subscriber, contributor) and i want to show the total users for each of those roles.

Can You Please point me also with the answer where i can put the code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to do it like this:

```
/* user count */
// Function to return user count 1
function total_count_bro() {
    $out             = '';   
    $user_count_data = count_users();
$avail_roles = $user_count_data['avail_roles'];
foreach ( $avail_roles as $role_key => $role_count ) {
        $out = $contributor = $avail_roles['contributor']; /* User role author  */'<br/>';
    }
    return $out;
    }
add_shortcode( 'users_count_bro', 'total_count_bro' );

// Function to return user count 2
function total_count_bro2() {
    $out             = '';   
    $user_count_data = count_users();
$avail_roles = $user_count_data['avail_roles'];
foreach ( $avail_roles as $role_key => $role_count ) {
        $out = $subscriber = $avail_roles['subscriber']; /* User role administrator */'<br/>';
    }
    return $out;
    }
add_shortcode( 'users_count_bro2', 'total_count_bro2' );
```

This will create the total count for the user by role and it will show the number count only.

Answer (score 0):

insert this code in your theme functions.php and use this shortcode [users_count_bro] to display where you want

```
function total_count_bro() {
    $out             = '';   
    $user_count_data = count_users();
    $avail_roles     = $user_count_data['avail_roles'];
    foreach ( $avail_roles as $role_key => $role_count ) {
        $out .= $role_key.':'.$role_count.'<br/>';
    }
    return $out;
}
add_shortcode( 'users_count_bro', 'total_count_bro' );
```

Comment: *The return value of a shortcode handler function is inserted into the post content output in place of the shortcode macro. Remember to use return and not echo - anything that is echoed will be output to the browser, but it won't appear in the correct place on the page.* https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Output

Comment: `count_users($strategy, $site_id)` documentation, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/count_users/, notes that counting can be either CPU- or memory-intensive depending on chosen counting strategy. If the site has only few users and very low traffic, then this might not be an issue. With a bigger userbase and busier site caching the count result into a transient, and not counting users again on every single pageload, can help save some resources.

Comment: Thank you for your time to answer, but this will show all roles and i want 2 role only like i mentioned above. If you can tell me to put 2 roles only with total count user of them and i can rename the 2 roles with another text. I hope you understand what i mean.